# Count hours passed over midnight

Tags: count, timespan

So, got myself into this thing that I thought would be a walk in the park, until I discovered how difficult it is working with things that needs to be calculated between hours that passes midnight.

In short, Im writing an app for work in which my vision is to visualize the production for the operators during their shift. Doing so, I need to declare shift times (which I got excellent help with in previous question), but I also need to calculate how many hours passed since the current shift started. This is in order to calculate efficiency (based on maxproducts (hourspassed * maxcapacity/h) / productsmade *100). Calculating the timespan works flawlessly, until nightshift starts. Their hours is 23:00-06:00 and I just cant get the accurate hours for when it overlaps midnight.

Current code used for calculating this is:

```
    Dim startTime As DateTime = Label46.Text ' Shift start Time

    Dim endTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") ' Current time 

    Dim span As TimeSpan = endTime.Subtract(startTime)

    Dim span2 As Double = (span.Hours)
    Label35.Text = span2 ' displays hours passed since shiftstart
```

I'm fresh at coding more or less, I'm still in a stage where I try my best to learn and understand every function instead of just using copy paste.
This has got my head in though, not even google seems to be willing to help me.

Thankful for ANY asisstance, or hints on this issue.

Im thinking an easy way of getting through it, such as using 00:00-06:00 as workinghours and then just do + 1 to passed hours during that timespan but seems cheesy..

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    If DateTime.Now > DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString & " 00:00:01" And DateTime.Now < DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString & " 05:59:59" Then
        Dim startTimeN As DateTime = "00:00:01" ' Shift start Time

        Dim endTimeN As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") ' Current time 

        Dim span1 As TimeSpan = endTimeN.Subtract(startTimeN)

        Dim span3 As Double = (span1.Hours)

        Label35.Text = span3 + 1
    Else

        Dim startTime As DateTime = Label6.Text.ToString() ' Shift start Time

        Dim endTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") ' Current time 

        Dim span As TimeSpan = endTime.Subtract(startTime)

        Dim span2 As Double = (span.Hours)
        Label35.Text = span2
    End If
```

But this feels like cheating.. ;)